# Remove all text and characters except some

Tags: excel

I have here some text strings

"16cg-301 -request","16cg-3368 - for review","16cg-3684 - for process"

what i would like to do is to remove all the text and characters except the number and the letters "cg" and - which is within the reference code.

Comment: What have you tried and where have you run into trouble?  Posting that can clarify the ambiguities in your requirement.  If you want everything after the last digit, or before the first space, or before the first `space dash` sequence, etc.

Comment: i want to remove all the text after the last digit

Comment: I'll post a formula in the answers

Answer (score 1):

If the string you want to extract is always before the first space in the full string then you can use `SEARCH` and `LEFT` to extract your reference code:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

This formula would take `16cg-3368` from `16cg-3368 - for review`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like suggested here
[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

With a replace regex similar to this

```
[^\dcg]*
```

or a match regex like this

```
^([0-9cg- ]+).*
```

else you could also work with a strange formule similar to this

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;1;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;1;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;2;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;2;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;3;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;3;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;4;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;4;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;5;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;5;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;6;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;6;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;7;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;7;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;8;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;8;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;9;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;9;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;10;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;10;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;11;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;11;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;12;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;12;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;13;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;13;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;14;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;14;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;15;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;15;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;16;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;16;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;17;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;17;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;18;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;18;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;19;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;19;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;20;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;20;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;21;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;21;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;22;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;22;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;23;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;23;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;24;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;24;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;25;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;25;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;26;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;26;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;27;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;27;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;28;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;28;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;29;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;29;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;30;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;30;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;31;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;31;1);"");IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2;32;1);"01234567890cg-")>0));MID(A2;32;1);""))
```

only works by now for less than 33 signs.
problem here will be that you will get unexpected behavior like this:

```
123cg-123 - Process => 123cg-123-c
```

after rereading , I think you should try an other approach than described in the question ;-)

Comment: If you are going to use a regex, you could probably match using `\d+cg-\d+`.  Your match regex above has a hyphen in the character class but not at the beginning or end.  Hence it will match everything from `g` to `space` which is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return everything up to and including the last digit, then try:

```
=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),seq))
```

`seq` is a named formula:  Formula ► Define Name

```
Name:  seq
Refers to:  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
```

seq returns an array of sequential numbers from 1 to 255.

```
mid(a1,seq,1)
```

returns an array consisting of the individual characters in the string in A1.  The leading minus sign converts the digits from strings to numbers.

The lookup function will then return the position of the last digit